# I need a WPF split toggle button

Tags: wpf-controls

Can anobody point me to where I might find one? Pref. free, I dont need to buy an entire control library for one control...

It should look like this (common on ribbon bars), and behave support toggle mode (like radio button, where only one button in the group can be depressed at a time).

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't style three RadioButtons to look the way you want them to?

Comment: Me specifically? Knowledge of Xaml. The first thing I usually do is see if someone has done it already, before I go and repeat their work.

Comment: True styles and triggers could achieve it. I have investigated completely restyling and templating a radio button, and also just changing the borders on a regular button (not possible) - both of them pretty much require reinventing the wheel in terms of getting the style to look the same as the default WPF chrome button, under all scenarios (normal, toggle, mousedown, mouseover, etc) - a lot of pain I would rather avoid. Currently my time is better spent on business logic. Cheers though - the prototype can live with plain radio buttons for the time being. I will look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is older but I had the same question. In WPF .Net 4.0 you can set the RibbonSplitButton value IsCheckable to True and you get what you are looking for.

```
<ribbon:RibbonSplitButton Label="Disk" Name="RibbonToggleButtonDisk" LargeImageSource="/Images/drive_med.png" IsCheckable="True" >
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="Used" Name="RibbonToggleButtonDiskUsed" SmallImageSource="/Images/drive_med.png" IsEnabled="false" IsChecked="True" />
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="Free" Name="RibbonToggleButtonDiskFree" SmallImageSource="/Images/drive_med.png" IsEnabled="False" />
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="Total" Name="RibbonToggleButtonDiskTotal" SmallImageSource="/Images/drive_med.png" IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="True" />
</ribbon:RibbonSplitButton>
```